# Azure AKS: Full access to new RBAC cluster with get-credentials without admin

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-rbac

If I create a brand-new AKS RBAC cluster from the Azure portal, in a resource group where I have *Contributor* role, and then run `az aks get-credentials` *without admin flag*, I am able to create and delete pods and namespaces, read cluster-wide secrets, and so on, using kubectl. This is *without* first logging in with `--admin` and creating any RBAC roles and bindings.

What is it that gives me these permissions? Based on [discussions](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/505#issuecomment-403170563) I [found](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/aks/control-kubeconfig-access) [online](https://medium.com/@weinong/azure-kubernetes-service-built-in-roles-8083b90e7ba), the non-admin version of `get-credentials` downloads kubeconfig settings for a *cluster user* role, which should allow me to login but not much else, out of the box.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We opened a support ticket and got an answer: Microsoft confirmed that this is a bug and something they're working on:

> Having "Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role" should not allow you to `get-credentials` with user profile.
>   However, there is a bug where the client certificate we return in `get-credentials --admin` is same as `get-credentials`. It pretty much means clusterUser is as good as clusterAdmin.

Comment: this is wrong, i mean this might be the case, but it has nothing to do with with the actual question asked. if you dont have AAD enabled cluster - it doesnt have 2 sets of configs

Comment: Please change the accepted answer. This is wrong. Below answer given by @4c74356b41 is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit of confusion here. So if you create a RBAC enabled cluster the `az aks get-credentials` will pull the admin config (so full access). You'd need to login creates roles\bindings\service accounts\users and [generate kubeconfigs for other users](https://jeremievallee.com/2018/05/28/kubernetes-rbac-namespace-user.html) so they will get exactly the permissions you want them to have.

If you, however, create a RBAC enabled cluster with [AAD integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-ad-integration) then the `az aks get-credentials` will pull credentials based on your AAD user and that will not work (pulling will work, accessing k8s will not) unless you configure appropriate roles\bindings inside k8s.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. So if I create an RBAC cluster and then log in using `az aks get-credentials` (without `--admin`), I am supposed to have full access? I was under the impression that I would only get full access if 1) I log in with `--admin` *and* 2) that I also have a cluster admin IAM role.

Comment: please read the answer, it explains everything. `--admin` gives cluster admin credentials, you dont need any roles for cluster admin to work, its configured by default

Comment: That is not my question. My question is: Why is it that I get full access **without** using the `--admin` flag?

Comment: read the answer, because the not AAD integrated cluster has only admin credentials that you can pull

Comment: FWIW the setup from AKS is fairly unintuitive, someone with the cluster user role gets cluster admin credentials. What's worse is that the credentials are generic (username of masterclient) and as it's client certificate auth, they **cannot** be revoked without rolling the entire cluster certificate authority.