# 401 not authorized to connect Dask KubeCluster

Tags: python, azure, kubernetes, dask, azure-aks

I'm trying to connect to AKS using [Dask KubeCluster](https://kubernetes.dask.org/en/latest/kubecluster.html). Doing the hello world of the tutorial:

- I'm using Windows with python 3.7.9
- I get my credentials doing `az aks get-credentials --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myName`, configuration file is written correctly at `C:\Users\MyName\.kube\config`.

I have configured a hello world `worker-spec.yml` given by

```
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: testdask
  labels:
    app: testdask

spec:
  containers:
  - name: testdask
    image: daskdev/dask:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 600m
        memory: 1Gi
      requests:
        cpu: 200m
        memory: 300Mi

  tolerations:
    - key: MyNodePool
      operator: "Equal"
      value: "true"
      effect: "NoSchedule"
  nodeSelector:
    nodepool: MyNodePool
```

And then I run the following code

```
from dask_kubernetes import KubeCluster, make_pod_spec
from dask.distributed import Client

from dask_kubernetes.auth import KubeConfig

import dask.array as da

worker_pod_spec = make_pod_spec('worker-spec.yml')

cluster = KubeCluster(
    worker_pod_spec,
    namespace="MyNameSpace",
    auth=KubeConfig(r"C:\Users\MyName\.kube\config"), # This is the default value
)

cluster.scale(2)

client = Client(cluster)

# Create a large array and calculate the mean
with client:
    array = da.ones((1000, 1000, 1000))
    print(array.mean().compute())  # Should print 1.0
```

I get a 401 status code error. When I create the pod using `kubectl` I have no problems and the pod is created

`kubectl apply -f worker-spec.yml -n MyNameSpace`

Here is my error

```
kubernetes_asyncio.client.exceptions.ApiException: (401)
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: <CIMultiDictProxy('Audit-Id': 'd792fa99-b011-4246-ae88-a651bfece35e', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Wed, 02 Feb 2022 18:17:55 GMT', 'Content-Length': '129')>
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}
```

Why using the python client I get 401 and when I use `kubectl` everthing works fine?

**EDIT**

I changed `az aks get-credentials --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myName` to `az aks get-credentials --resource-group myResourceGroup --admin --name myName` and everything worked, the problem now is how to get the correct credentials for non-admin users who have permissions

Comment: i am not windos mater but `C\Users\MyName\.kube\config` is it correct path ? or we need to give `:` like `C:\Users\MyName\.kube\config` also just try with `def main():
    config.load_kube_config()` by default it take file from same path so.

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/6709b753b4ad2e09aa472b6452bbad9f96e264e3/examples/create_deployment_from_yaml.py

Comment: The path was a typing error, i edited it

Comment: Are you sure that the the kubeconfig you're getting from `az aks get-credentials` has Kubernetes RBAC permissions on the `MyNameSpace` kubernetes namespace? It seems like your HTTP response is coming from the Kubernetes API, judging from  the `"apiVersion":"v1"` in the response body.

Comment: The admin created the Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) as the [docs](https://kubernetes.dask.org/en/latest/kubecluster.html) and still got the same error . The administrator who has access to the entire cluster, ran the script and also got 401

Comment: Maybe I need other command to get credentials? I can't find more documentation

Answer (score 0):

The problem now is how to get the correct credentials for `non-admin` users who have permissions

As answered by [User 4c74356b41 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6067741/4c74356b41):

- if you create a RBAC enabled cluster the ```az aks get-credentials` `` will pull the admin config.
- If you, however, create a RBAC enabled cluster with [AAD integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-ad-integration) then the `az aks get-credentials` will pull credentials based on your AAD user and that will not work

  To understand more about `az aks get-credentials` roles check following references:  [Azure AKS: Full access to new RBAC cluster with get-credentials without admin - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487811/azure-aks-full-access-to-new-rbac-cluster-with-get-credentials-without-admin) , [node.js - Azure Kubernetes Service- Get kubeconfig for non-admin AD app identity - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374878/azure-kubernetes-service-get-kubeconfig-for-non-admin-ad-app-identity), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-identity and https://medium.com/@weinong/azure-kubernetes-service-built-in-roles-8083b90e7ba